# Get general information about google workspace organization

Tags: google-admin-sdk

My goal is to have some information about a Google Workspace organization in particular I would need:

- main domain/domains
- Organization name
- Logo of the organization

And maybe other similar info.

I'm trying to use the SDK offered by google to make queries for what I need, in particular I'm using the DirectoryApi.

But it seems I can't find any resource that gives me those infos about the Google workspace of my admin account.

Directory API ref: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the domain you can use the [domains.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/domains/list) method. With this method  you can also check if it is the [primary domain or not](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/domains#resource:-domain).

[image]

For the organization name you need the [customers.get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/domains/list) method. It returns the organization's name as you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/customers#customerpostaladdress).

[image]

Now, I think there is no API to get the organization's logo. The closest thing would be the users profile picture using the [users.photo.get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users.photos/get) method.

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful!